# Entity Framework 6 doesn't save navigated object (state is Unchanged) if parent object has all properties virtual

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, virtual

I have following classes:

```
 public class A
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; } //virtual here raises error!

    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

 public class B
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string title { get; set; }

    }
```

and code:

```
   var context = new Model1();
    var dbSet = context.Set<A>();
    var dbSet1 = context.Set<B>();

    var a = dbSet.Find(1);
    var b = a.B;
    b.title = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    int changes1 = context.SaveChanges();
    if (changes1 == 0)
        throw new Exception("not updated");
```

if I remove "virtual" from property ID in class A everything is working. I need the property virtual in order to use the model also in nhibernate.

thanks

Comment: why do you want the Key property to be virtual? virtual allows you to override the implementation and it allows EF to lazy load your properties. I guess for a Key property it doesn't make that much sense.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce it, and apparently it's EF6 bug.

I can suggest 2 workarounds. Either (1) make **all** `B` members `virtual` as well, or (2) **eager load** (lazy and explicit loading doesn't work) the navigation property before editing it.

i.e. instead of

```
var a = dbSet.Find(1); // doesn't work
```

use

```
var a = dbSet.Include(e => e.B).First(e => e.ID == 1); // works
```